# Menu showing outline key sequences

Tags: key-bindings

I am using easy menu with a keymap, but instead of seeing `H-b`, `H-m`, `H-w`, `H-v`, I still get `C-c @ C-t`, `C-c @ C-c`, `C-c @ C-e`, `C-c @ C-a`, when clicking upon the minor mode lighter.

```
(defvar tika-kymap

  (let ( (pfmap (make-sparse-keymap)) )

    (keymap-set pfmap "H-b" #'outline-hide-body)
    (keymap-set pfmap "H-m" #'outline-hide-entry)
    (keymap-set pfmap "H-w" #'outline-show-entry)
    (keymap-set pfmap "H-v" #'outline-show-all)

    pfmap))


(defun tika-ezmenu-popup ()
  (easy-menu-define tika-ezmenu tika-kymap "Tika Menu"
    '("Tika Ezm"
        ["Hide Body"  outline-hide-body  t]
        ["Hide Entry" outline-hide-entry t]
        "---"
        ["Show Entry" outline-show-entry t]
        ["Show All"   outline-show-all   t])))


;;;###autoload
(define-minor-mode tika-minor-mode
  :init-value nil
  :lighter " Tika"
  :keymap tika-kymap

  (if tika-minor-mode
        (do-this)
     (do-that)))

(add-hook 'tika-minor-mode-hook #'tika-ezmenu-popup)
```

Comment: Please edit this question to remove everything that's relevant to the otherwise-duplicate question you just posted, [Making certain key sequences show up in lighter menu](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/77952). Just one question per post, please.

Answer (score 2):

There's a bunch of things wrong with your code. I fixed them all. It should look like this.

First for anyone reading this, this code will not work in versions of emacs earlier than 29 because the function `keymap-set` does not exist in prior versions.

```lisp
    (defvar tika-kymap
      (let ((pfmap (make-sparse-keymap)))
        (keymap-set pfmap "H-b" #'outline-hide-body)
        (keymap-set pfmap "H-m" #'outline-hide-entry)
        (keymap-set pfmap "H-w" #'outline-show-entry)
        (keymap-set pfmap "H-v" #'outline-show-all)
        pfmap))
    
    (easy-menu-define tika-ezmenu tika-kymap "Tika Menu"
      '("Tika Ezm"
          ["Hide Body"  outline-hide-body  t]
          ["Hide Entry" outline-hide-entry t]
          "---"
          ["Show Entry" outline-show-entry t]
          ["Show All"   outline-show-all   t]))
    
    ;;;###autoload
    (define-minor-mode tika-minor-mode
      "docstring goes here."
      :init-value nil
      :lighter " Tika"
      :keymap tika-kymap)
```

It's unclear to me why you thought the macro defining the menu should be inside a function called inside a hook attached to the enabling of the minor mode. It makes me think there's a lot of things about how emacs works that you're still unfamiliar with. This is fairly normal. Emacs has been around about 50 years now, and has been in constant development, starting from before any kind of "standard patterns" ever existed in the world, so emacs has its own way of thinking about everything. This being said, if you want to accomplish anything, you need to spend some time getting familiar with the details of emacs, including emacs-lisp.

One reason why this is really important, even crucial, is because emacs ships with a very large amount of existing, functional, robust, and highly valuable source code in emacs lisp, and when you're able to read this code, you'll be able to figure out fairly quickly a lot of your own small questions like this.

There's also a lot of tools in emacs that are intended to help you *explore* emacs itself.

1. the `*scratch*` buffer allows you to write emacs-lisp, and you can execute that code with `C-x C-e`, so you can load code in emacs and see the result very quickly
2. if you prefer fuller REPLs, `M-x ielm RET` will open a REPL for you
3. the emacs-lisp manual will teach you everything you need about how emacs lisp works, including the data structures specific to emacs, and you can use the REPLs to play with all of this
4. when you can read emacs-lisp, you will want to check out the book Mastering Emacs https://www.masteringemacs.org/ to teach you how to navigate through emacs buffers and elisp code as effectively as possible (all of it is available directly through emacs' documentation, but it is broken down and organized in a very easy-to-digest manner)

I have looked back at the past multiple weeks of questions you're asking, and you are coming to emacs.SE to ask very, very tiny questions about a bigger project. The result is very frustrating for all of us, because your questions lack crucial context, and then you correct us for not following the context you didn't share with us.

Please, when you ask questions, explain the larger context, so we can avoid falling, over and over, into the XY problem ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem ), which, in short, is that you're asking us to fix your broken solution instead of asking us to fix your real problem.

Comment: "*when you ask questions, explain the larger context*" --- If one has a strong enough ability to **abstract** a class of problems and the ability to **extract** the key of a specific problem, then there's no need to provide a larger context when he asks questions. A larger context can sometimes be mentally taxing on those who read your question description, and this is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @shynur Yes, although that is orthogonal to what I'm saying. What is happening is that he's asking us how to construct 25 sentences, sentence by sentence, instead of telling us that he wants to build a particular paragraph. And the sentences are always wrong because they're not connected to the paragraph.

Comment: I want the possibility of using different menus and is the reason I made `tika-ezmenu-popup`.

Comment: I think it is perfectly acceptable to have a function that implements `easy-menu-define` and then introduce a minor mode hook to it.

Comment: At any level, the problem has not been solved because I do not see the key sequence bindings defined by `tika-kymap` in the lighter.  Instead the key sequence bindings for `outline-minor-mode` are shown.

Comment: *"you need to spend some time getting familiar with the details of emacs, including emacs-lisp."* Amen. Alas, it's been suggested to OP many times...

Comment: Where does the documentation say about showing the key sequences in menu.  I need to look into specific things.  Getting familiar with details of emacs does not convey useful information that I can focus on.

Comment: @Dilna "the problem has not been solved because I do not see the key sequence bindings defined by tika-kymap in the lighter. Instead the key sequence bindings for outline-minor-mode are shown." -- I evaluated the code in this response in emacs 28 and it worked. Quit out of emacs and try again. This answer is correct. If it does not work for you, then there is something you have not shared with us.

Comment: @Dilna "I need to look into specific things" : yes, but without gaining a deeper understanding, you are making circuitous progress on your project. It seems you do not realize it, but many of the questions you asked wasted hours of your life, and this will continue. Your choice to not read the manual is wasting your future time. You say you are in a hurry, but paradoxically, you choose the path that will be slower. If you are in a hurry, then open the manual. Now -- in *THIS* particular case, it is difficult to get help from the manual, this is why I did research and answered this question.

Comment: @Dilna if this answers your question, please mark this as the correct answer for future emacs.SE users.