# Making certain key sequences show up in the lighter menu

Tags: key-bindings, mode-line

With the following code, how can I get `H-b`, `H-m`, `H-w`, `H-v`, to show up in the lighter menu ?

```
(defvar tika-kymap
  (let ((pfmap (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (keymap-set pfmap "H-b" #'outline-hide-body)
    (keymap-set pfmap "H-m" #'outline-hide-entry)
    (keymap-set pfmap "H-w" #'outline-show-entry)
    (keymap-set pfmap "H-v" #'outline-show-all)
    pfmap))

(easy-menu-define tika-ezmenu tika-kymap "Tika Menu"
  '("Tika Ezm"
      ["Hide Body"  outline-hide-body  t]
      ["Hide Entry" outline-hide-entry t]
      "---"
      ["Show Entry" outline-show-entry t]
      ["Show All"   outline-show-all   t]))

;;;###autoload
(define-minor-mode tika-minor-mode
  "docstring goes here."
  :init-value nil
  :lighter " Tika"
  :keymap tika-kymap)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have uploaded a video as proof that this code, pasted into emacs, works perfectly and shows the keybindings into the lighter menu. This is a non-question.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0B0a6ZPyHaQ